# Transform a data frame

Tags: r

Given a data frame named "Table" like this (with value1, value2, ..., value100):

```
 Month         Currency      value1    value2     
  Jan            euro         210       200

  Jan            dollar       120       300

  Feb            euro         100       280

  Feb            dollar       200       150
```

I want to get this:

```
              value1             value2
 Month    euro    dollar     euro      dollar 
  Jan     210      120       200        300

  Feb     100      200       280        150
```

I tried this in order to create column names for euro and dollar: `Table <- spread(Table,Currency)`.

But I got an error:

> Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object '' not found

Can you help me how I can get a format like this that I want?

Comment: YOu can do `library(data.table);dcast(setDT(df1), Month ~ Currency, value.var = c("value1", "value2"))`

Comment: I got an error like this when i tried your code: Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : 
  attempt to apply non-function

Comment: Yo can use reshape2 and xtabs ... library(reshape2); xtabs(value ~ Month + Currency + variable, data = melt(Table, id = c("Month", "Currency")))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with package `reshape2`.

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(melt(Table, id.vars = c("Month", "Currency")), Month ~ Currency + variable)
#  Month dollar_value1 dollar_value2 euro_value1 euro_value2
#1   Feb           200           150         100         280
#2   Jan           120           300         210         200
```

**Data**

```
Table <- read.table(text = "
Month         Currency      value1    value2     
  Jan            euro         210       200
  Jan            dollar       120       300
  Feb            euro         100       280
  Feb            dollar       200       150
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` would probably be the easiest way:

```
dat <- read.table(text= " Month         Currency      value1    value2     
  Jan            euro         210       200

           Jan            dollar       120       300

           Feb            euro         100       280

           Feb            dollar       200       150", header = TRUE)

library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dat), Month ~ Currency, value.var = c(rep(paste0("value", 1:2))))
```

Just change the `2` in `c(rep(paste0("value", 1:2)))` to whatever the final `value` is.